# How to get custom header from metadata of incoming request in grpc-gateway

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

Here is my CORS policy set to have a custom header

```
return http.ListenAndServe(":"+port,
        handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization","Custom-header"}),
            handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"}),
            handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}))(mux))
```

And now in my grpc server, when the call hits I am trying to read the header using below code snippet

```
md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", ok))
    }

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", md))
```

However, the header **Authorization** is getting from the metadata, but the **Custom-header** is not showing up.
How do I get my Custom-header and its value?

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all, you may need to write a custom header matcher: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305337/how-to-send-metadata-from-grpc-gateway-to-go-grpc-server?rq=2

Comment: @segFault That doesn't help me

Comment: Can you enable debug logs and make sure the header is there?